# c# wont use an new overrided method in the base class

Tags: c#, events, inheritance, overriding

I have something like this

```
class Super{
  public event EventHandler MyEvent;
  public void Enable(){
   MyEvent+=AtEvent;
  }

  public void Disable(){
   MyEvent-=AtEvent;
  }

  protected void AtEvent(object sender,EventArgs e){
   AllThatJazz();
  }
}

class Child:Super{
 protected new void AtEvent(object sender,EventArgs e){
  try{
   base.AtEvent(sender,e);
  }catch(ObjectDisposedException){}
 }
}


class Program{
 public static void Main(){
   Child c = new Child();
   c.Enable();
 }
}
```

c.Enable() attaches the base class's event handler to MyEvent, not the Child's new AtEvent method. Can somebody explain this?
I appreciate suggestions  for alternatives, but note that Super is in a separate assembly.

Comment: This does not compile. `base.AtEvent()` does not have enough arguments.

Comment: Look up the virtual and override c# keywords.

Comment: Stay away from the `new` modifier in method declarations, unless you enjoy obscure behavior of your program...

Comment: Super is in a separate assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AtEvent` is not virtual, it's sealed.  You're calling it from a method in the base class, so it is going to be statically bound to that specific implementation of the method.  It would need to be virtual (and overridden instead of shadowed) to call the most-derived implementation of that method, or it would need to be called from a reference to the object that was statically typed to `Child`, which is not currently the case at the place in which you call `AtEvent`.

Comment: what do you mean by "called from a reference to the object that was statically typed to `Child`"

Comment: @Nromaai I mean exactly what I said.  You need to access `AtEvent` on a variable of type `Child` to access the child's implementation.  Currently your code is accessing that method from a variable that is of the type of the parent class, so the parent's implementation is what is used.

Comment: That doesnt seem to help - such a variable would have to be in scope in the Super class....

Comment: @Nromaai Yes, and that of course is likely not possible.  Such is the nature of sealed methods.  The whole point of sealing methods is that you don't *want* to call the more derived implementation, and you don't want an inheriting class to be able to change the binding of your method call to their own implementation.  If they *wanted* to call the more derived implementation, then the method should be virtual.  The code behaves this way because *this is exactly how sealed methods were designed to work*.